# Extra cells visible after results from UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a iOS 7 UITableView populated by a CoreData DB; it's working great.  I added a UISearchDisplayController that searches the database; this works well except for the small case where a search would only display a few results (less than the number that can fit on the screen).  In that case, I end up seeing extra blank cells that don't scroll below my results. Here's an example:

[image: UISearch Weirdness]

The width of the divider between the non-scrolling lines seems to be controlled by the custom width of the 'Separator Insets' in the storybord options for my Table View, so I know that's where they're from, I just don't know how to stop them from showing up.  In my storyboard the Content of the Table View is set to 'Dynamic Prototypes' with just 1 prototype cell.  I've also attached the search bar with scope to my table view in the storyboard.

Here's some of the code I use to manage the search interaction.

```
#pragma mark - Search
// This gets called when you start typing text into the search bar
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)_controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    self.searchString = searchString;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [self setFetchedResultsControllerWithContext:self.managedObjectContext andPredicate:[self searchPredicateGenerator]];

    return YES;
}

// This gets called when you change the search bar scope
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = searchOption;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [self setSearchBarPlaceholdersForCase:searchOption];

    [self setFetchedResultsControllerWithContext:self.managedObjectContext andPredicate:[self searchPredicateGenerator]];

    return YES;
}

// To generate search predicates
-(NSPredicate *)searchPredicateGenerator {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ AND ((title CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\") OR (descriptionText CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\"))",
                                             [self stringPredicateForCase:self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex],
                                             self.searchString,
                                             self.searchString ]];
}

// This gets called when you cancel or close the search bar
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    self.searchString = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [self setFetchedResultsControllerWithContext:self.managedObjectContext andPredicate:self.filterPredicate];
}

// to tell the search controller which cells to use here
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView registerClass:[TWLTableCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MarkIdentifier"];
    tableView.rowHeight = TWLTABLE_ROW_HEIGHT; // or some other height
}
```

I've avoided pasting whole files here to keep the question shorter but if you need other code snippets (or any other info) please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no responses after about 2 weeks. Please let me know if I can provide any more info, etc to help track down this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Story Board -> Table View -> Attributes Inspector -> Style -> Grouped

Comment: This works, but I don't really understand why.  It did mess up the height of all my cells (made them half as tall), but I was able to diff the storyboard file before and after and fix the appropriate pixels heights to be the same as before. Thanks!

Comment: This is the standard way used in the iphone settings page. At least it looks good :)